# MySQL - Use LIMIT with GROUP BY

Tags: mysql

I've looked at a lot of questions with similar titles but none have really helped in my particular case:

**QUERY**

```
SELECT YEAR(start_time) AS year, MONTH(start_time) AS month, COUNT(*) AS calls, to_number
FROM calls
WHERE organisation_id = 123 AND direction = 'inbound'
GROUP BY YEAR(start_time), MONTH(start_time), to_number
ORDER BY YEAR(start_time), MONTH(start_time), DAY(start_time) ASC
```

This almost gives me what I want with the number of calls  to each number per month but I want to limit the number of results for each month. At the moment it will return the count for every single number per month which could be anything from zero to several hundred.

e.g. in the current query, results for this month could be:

```
year | month | calls | to_number   |
------------------------------------
2014 |   6   |  1856 | 44123456789 |
2014 |   6   |  1800 | 44123456788 |
2014 |   6   |  1456 | 44123456790 |
2014 |   6   |  1256 | 44123456791 |
2014 |   6   |  1151 | 44123456792 |
2014 |   6   |  1056 | 44123456793 |
```

so, 6 results for that month when I want to `LIMIT` it to 5 (the ones with the most number of calls).

**EDIT**

**SQLFiddle** http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f915bd/1

**UPDATE**

I've tried to replicate this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/15585351/634120 but because I am using months **and** years it seems to be an unsuitable approach to solving the problem.

```
SELECT   to_number, GROUP_CONCAT(year(start_time), month(start_time) ORDER BY id DESC)      grouped_year
FROM     calls
WHERE direction = 'inbound' AND organisation_id = 123
GROUP BY to_number
```

The result of this can't be used in the next stage of the query because the results contain the month and year, e.g. `20146` instead of `2014` like in the original question, which means the year and month of the timestamp was `2014-06`. Since the next part of the answer relies on the parsing of this `GROUP_CONCAT` result it's not applicable to my scenario.

I then tried to incorporate [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14170492/634120) into my query but the error I get running that is `unknown column start_time in field list`:

```
SELECT YEAR(start_time), MONTH(start_time), to_number, COUNT(*)
FROM (SELECT YEAR(start_time), MONTH(start_time), to_number, COUNT(*), IF(@lasttype = (@lasttype:=a.type), @index:=@index+1, @index:=0) indx 
      FROM (SELECT YEAR(start_time), MONTH(start_time), to_number,  COUNT(*) 
            FROM calls
            WHERE organisation_id = 123 AND direction = 'inbound'
            GROUP BY to_number, YEAR(start_time), MONTH(start_time)
            ORDER BY YEAR(start_time), MONTH(start_time) ASC
            ) h, (SELECT @lasttype:='', @index:=0) AS a
    ) h 
WHERE h.indx <= 5;
```

I don't believe that this is a duplicate of [Using LIMIT within GROUP BY to get N results per group?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2129693/mysql-using-limit-within-group-by-to-get-n-results-per-group) since that question deals only with years whereas I am taking both months and years into consideration, therefore the answers given there that rely on that fact aren't suitable for this question.

Comment: `6` is actually the month and not the count.

Comment: @juergend, yes, the month and number of results are both `6`, just a coincidence.

Comment: The query as written cannot produce multiple results per month, because the `group by` has only year and month.

Comment: @GordonLinoff, it's producing multiple results per month as it is just now, just not limiting them, unless that's what you meant?

Comment: Group By user in query with year and month will return only one row for a month wih particular year, it can not return more than one row.

Comment: @developerCK I see what's causing the confusion now, I left out `to_number` in the `GROUP BY` clause, I've edited the question now.